# getting MAC layer data from higher layers (TraciDEMO)

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using VEINS 4.4 and trying to get/use MAC layer data real-time during the simulation such as from TraciDemo11p.cc?

The data can be mac address, average mac delay, etc.

Is there any way to do that without changing too much code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ simulations are written in C++, so all code is available to you for inspection. If you find the C++ code that defines the behavior of the MAC layer you can augment it with result recording statements (see [the OMNeT++ user manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/)) to log any and all internal state.